# What election algorithm does microsoft failover cluster use?

Tags: failovercluster, bully-algorithm

I cannot find anything about the algorithm it uses as primary node election algorithm.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Is it a bully algorithm, or ring algorithm, or some other algorithms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but here is what I found on a website that explains Failover Clustering:

> Quorum implementation in Windows Server
>
> When a failover cluster is brought online (assuming one node at a
>   time), the first disk brought online is one that will be associated
>   the quorum model deployed. To do this, the failover cluster executes a
>   disk arbitration algorithm to take ownership of that disk on the first
>   node initially making it as offline and then going through a few
>   checks. When the cluster is satisfied that there are no problems with
>   the quorum, it is brought online. The same thing happens with the
>   other disks. After all the disks come online, the Cluster Disk Driver
>   sends periodic reservations every 3 seconds to keep ownership of the
>   disk.
>
> If for some reason the cluster loses communication over all of its
>   networks, the quorum arbitration process begins. The outcome is
>   straightforward: the node that currently owns the reservation on the
>   quorum is the defending node and the other nodes become challengers.
>   When a challenger detects that it cannot communicate, it issues a
>   request to break any existing reservations it owns via a buswide SCSI
>   reset in Windows Server 2003 and persistent reservation in Windows
>   Server 2008. Seven seconds after this reset happens, the challenger
>   attempts to gain control of the quorum and then a few things can
>   happen: If the node that already owns the quorum is up and running, it
>   still has the reservation of the quorum disk thus the challenger
>   cannot take ownership and it shuts down the Cluster Service; If the
>   node that owns the quorum fails and gives up its reservation, then the
>   challenger can take ownership after 10 seconds elapse. The challenger
>   can reserve the quorum, bring it online, and subsequently take
>   ownership of other resources in the cluster; If no node of the cluster
>   can gain ownership of the quorum, the Cluster Service is stopped on
>   all nodes.

I hope that helps. Good luck :)

The link to the website, so you can read more: http://networksandservers.blogspot.com/2011/04/failover-clustering-i.html